# Code does not work for big numbers

Tags: java

Apparently there is a bug I cannot figure out in the following code. The code is meant to solve [project euler 429](http://projecteuler.net/problem=429), and seem to work just fine with small numbers (I made a much simpler code that works untill x=10 to verify that). I must say the last hour I spent trying to figure it out (in vain), made believe the code does not work due to an error I haven't got the knowledge to solve - and that's why I'm here.

My request to you is this: Could you tell me why would this code not work for big numbers, even though it works well for smaller ones? *(I believe it isn't neccessary to understand my code in order to find the bug)*

Comment: What do you mean by 'does not work'? - does it throw an exception, return the wrong result...?

Comment: Nope, it simply gives a wrong result

Comment: Btw, If any of you need I will gladly try to explain the idea behind the code

Comment: What is the result for big numbers? is it negative?

Comment: The result I got is 844910848 which is not accepted by project euler, apparently.

Comment: BigInteger.nextProbablePrime() appears to only return the next *probable* prime, not the next *definite* prime. Is the point of this to add all primes? What're the odds that nextProbablePrime is actually returning a non-prime number?

Comment: AFAIK project euler problems can't be easily solved by using brute force (as you're currently trying). Instead, try to come up with a different strategy. For example, in 4! = 24, you just need the prime numbers (except for 2) and its contrapart factor (I don't know how to spell it in English), which in this case is 3 (and its contrapart, 8), and of course 1 and 24 (1 and n). After this, you just have to summarize the values of the square exponent of these numbers and calculate the modulus with 1 000 000 009.

Comment: Additional note: to calculate prime numbers, it would be better to use [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) instead of `BigInteger#nextProbablePrime`.

Comment: Thanks for your help luiggi! But believe me, this isn't brute force and I am pretty experienced with project euler's problems. With brute force I wouldn't make it past 15!

Comment: regarding nextProbablePrime, do any of you have any info about it? (so I know for later times just how much I can rely on it)

Comment: The usage of `BigInteger` for almost all the operations shows that somehow your main algorithm still relies on brute force.

Comment: I know the code isn't perfect (their problems are designed to be solved in less than 1 minute as far as I know), but I also I never aimed for perfection. As long as the run time is reasonable (less than 5 hours) - I consider the code good enough. Thanks for your help! I'll try to use a different prime generating function and see if the result changes.

Comment: There's a lot of numbers in there... You should be explicit at least about which numbers you mean and where is the threshold.

Comment: 5 hours! Sorry to say, but these problems can be solved in less than 5 minutes using the right approach (which is the main idea behind these problems).

Comment: ah it says "The probability that the number returned by this method is composite does not exceed 2^-100", so I suppose the 'probable' referes to it not being relyable for cryptographic purposes - thus the problem is probably somewhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a simple misreading:

> Find `S(100 000 000!)` modulo `1 000 000 009`.

vs.

```
int x=1000000000;
```

Count the zeros.

The algorithm is not bad, although it could be improved by

- using a Sieve to find the primes,
- avoiding `BigInteger`, `long` is sufficient (if done right).

Comment: Ah thanks Daniel but this is far from the source of the problem. The code works like this:

Comment: @user2435678 You might have a bug in `howManyDevidors`, that one's a bit of a mess. I extrapolated that it works since it does for small numbers, but I may be wrong with that.

Comment: The code works like this: I found that all the unitary divisors of n! is all the combinaions made from the list of all primes to n, powered by how many times they exist in the composition to primes of all numbers from 1-n. (hope you understood this - I wouldn't if I were you)

Comment: I understood that (though you could have written the algorithm simpler), that's why I said the algorithm isn't bad. Another possible source for a bug would be that `nextProbablePrime` skips a prime - I'd be surprised, though.

Comment: pffffff daniel!!! I... I can't believe this. I haven't even read well your post, I thought you think I forgot the factorial. Hehe im excited. Thanks for the help!!! I'll report you back when the function finishes.

Comment: It spat out the right result for me (although it's relatively slow, your `howManyDevidors` [by the way, the word is "divisors"] is pretty inefficient (you can improve it much [I haven't tested, should be much, though] by using `modPow`).

Comment: modpow you say.. huh good to know, maybe next time. I added BigInteger only after I wrote the code, in hope this is somehow the source of the problem (I was very fraustrated)

Comment: I have just done a small experiment, how fast `nextProbablePrime()` is - it's very slow, takes over 20 seconds to reach a million here, that would be something like half an hour to reach 100 million. So to speed it up, the major improvement would be a sieve to find the primes. Sieving to 100 million would not take more than a few seconds even with a very unsophisticated implementation.

Comment: Thanks very much Daniel! - I too got the right result at last. So you're saying the long run time was only a result of the built-in functions I used? great =) I'll get more into "sieving" in another time, it's already too late here.